# How to remove punctuations of a list in Python?

Tags: python, nlp, html-lists, punctuation

I am totally a newbie to nltk and python. I have been given a task to extract all the texts from an url. I have tried and able to extract text from a specified url after reading the nltk documentation. My main concern is how to do I remove the special characters (like .,-,"",'',!,) from the extracted list. The below mentioned code is not working for the text inside the `<li>` `</li>` tag of a html web page. Thus, always dot `.` is appended to the last word of the text inside the `<li>` tag. Any help is deeply appreciated. The source code is as follows.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import urllib.request
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronics') 
f=open('corpus.txt','w+')
html = response.read() 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser") 
text = soup.get_text(strip=True)
tokens = [t for t in text.split()]
clean_tokens = tokens[:] 
sr = stopwords.words('english') 
for token in tokens: 
if token in sr: 
   clean_tokens.remove(token) 
   freq = nltk.FreqDist(clean_tokens) 
   for normalize,val in freq.items(): 
       lemmatizer=WordNetLemmatizer()
       corpus_refi=lemmatizer.lemmatize(str(normalize) + ':' + str(val), pos="a")
       corpus_refi=corpus_refi.lower()
       print(corpus_refi)
```

Comment: you are missing a closing `'` on this line `response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://wikipedia.org) `

Comment: It has now been edited. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i correctly understood your question, but if you want to detect punctuation, you can do something like.

```
from string import punctuation
punc = set(punctuation)
# then inside your for loop, you can either skip if
if token not in punc:
```

in case the token contains multiple characters which one is a punctuation. To remove it you can do something like

```
token = translate(token.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
```